# Does adding a null column to a postgres table cause a lock?

Tags: postgresql, alter-table

I think I read somewhere that running an `ALTER TABLE foo ADD COLUMN baz text` on a postgres database will not cause a read or write lock. Setting a default value causes locking, but allowing a null default prevents a lock.

I can't find this in the documentation, though. Can anyone point to a place that says, definitively, if this is true or not?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The different sorts of locks and when they're used are mentioned in the doc in
[Table-level Locks](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html). For instance, Postgres 11's `ALTER TABLE` may acquire a `SHARE UPDATE EXCLUSIVE`, `SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE`, or `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock.

Postgres 9.1 through 9.3 claimed to support two of the above three but actually [forced `Access Exclusive` for all variants of this command](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL9_3_STABLE/src/backend/commands/tablecmds.c#L2729-L2755). This limitation was [lifted in Postgres 9.4](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/commit/e5550d5fec66aa74caad1f79b79826ec64898688) but **`ADD COLUMN` remains at `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE`** by design.

It's easy to check in the source code because there's a function dedicated to establishing the lock level needed for this command in various cases: `AlterTableGetLockLevel` in `src/backend/commands/tablecmds.c`.

---

Concerning **how much time the lock is held**, once acquired:

- When the column's default value is NULL, the column's addition should be very quick because it doesn't need a table rewrite: it's only an update in the catalog.
- When the column has a non-NULL default value, it depends on PostgreSQL version: with version 11 or newer, there is no immediate rewriting of all the rows, so it should be as fast as the NULL case. But with version 10 or older, the table is entirely rewritten, so it may be quite expensive depending on the table's size.

Comment: That is awesome -- it never occurred to me to look at the source, and if it had, I wouldn't have known where to look. Surprisingly readable.

I'm looking through it to see if I can find evidence that it is only a short lock for adding nullable columns, but I don't know enough to tell for sure. Maybe something in ATExecAddColumn? https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/commands/tablecmds.c#L4383

Answer (score 37):

Adding new null column will lock the table for very very short time since no need to rewrite all data on disk. While adding column with default value requires PostgreSQL to make new versions of all rows and store them on the disk. And during that time table will be locked.

So when you need to add column with default value to big table it's recommended to add null value first and then update all rows in small portions. This way you'll avoid high load on disk and allow autovacuum to do it's job so you'll not end up doubling table size.

Answer (score 13):

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html#AEN57290

"Adding a column with a non-null default or changing the type of an existing column will require the entire table and indexes to be rewritten."

So the documentation only specifies when the table is not rewritten.
There will always be a lock, but it will be very short in case the table is not to be rewritten.

Comment: WARN: in 9.4 an higher: Adding a column with a DEFAULT clause or changing the type of an existing column will require the entire table and its indexes to be rewritten.

Answer (score 1):

> Setting a default value causes locking, but allowing a null default prevents a lock.

The other answers are outdated. Since [Postgres 11](https://www.enterprisedb.com/blog/adding-new-table-columns-default-values-postgresql-11), adding a column with a default value (null or otherwise), will not require a rewrite of the table. It will only lock the table for a few milliseconds so essentially not locking it all. Adding a column with a default value is now a fast and cheap operation!