# Mysql: ALTER TABLE without locking the table?

Tags: mysql, sql, locking

I want to add column to an existing table.

Is there a manner to alter the table without locking it?

Comment: I would like to type just NO but it doesn't allow me, since at least 15 characters are required.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19525083/does-adding-a-null-column-to-a-postgres-table-cause-a-lock. please have a look @Eldar .

Answer (score 2):

No, that's not possible.

However, adding a nullable column or a not null column with a constant (immutable) default value is merely a catalog change and only takes a very short time (typically "milliseconds" if the lock can be obtained). But during that time, the exclusive lock can't be avoided.